# Limit playback duration server-side

Tags: php, actionscript-3, nginx, limit, flv

I'm looking for solution that will allow me limiting user playback duration.

Many services on the net (like putlocker, dead megavideo.com or videobb) limit's playback time for free users. Is there any complete, open source solution for that? I use nginx to serve secured flv files, but I don't have any possibility to limit playback time for non-premium users.

What method, or complete solutions can I use to limit it? I'm using my own fork of video.js-swf that supports pseudo-streaming.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way would be to modify the output file (to completely break it - so that the user cannot just download it and see it in some player, insert some random sequences of bytes, etc... something) AND inject cue points. Your player should read the cuepoints and if the 'stamp' matches, it should cut the playback and show a warning message.

In worst case you can do only the cuepoint stuff. But in that case you have to be aware that the more skilled users will sniff the file and see it in some VLC or something...

Comment: In Wowza we have setPlayDuration(), but I'm looking for something other that this (I look for free, open-source solution). In case of Wowza you have streamed only that part to user you specify as setPlayDuration's argument.

Comment: Neither of the services you mentioned use streaming. So what exactly do you want to do, stream or progressive load? I have told you how to do it with progressive load.

Comment: I use http pseudo-streaming - I think it's the easiest one and it's supported by most of players available.